# global scope bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

is it possible to create a single bootstrap popover and be able to call it on whatever element clicks it?

I am making a list to track any bugs on a website and the goal is when the remove bug button is pressed the popover will come with a text box and ask you to input a solution to how the bug was resolved.

I know i can do this with a modal and have the fields populated accordingly and share one modal across the page. But i find they are obtrusive and i don't much like them.  and with popovers i don't know how to make a single instance. I am having no luck with that because the markup is essentially paired with the link that triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do.  You can pass a function into the content for the popover.  That function would be common to all popovers.

Click the button below to run the code.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn').popover({
    content: function() {
      // do anything you want here.
      
      $('.btn').popover('hide');

      return 'this appears for all the popovers!  The button you clicked said: "' + $(this).html() + '"';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">click me</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">or click me</a>
</p>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">or even click me</a>
</p>
```